# How do I resolve an Error PHP webservice PHP + Android?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I have a webservice in php:

```
<?php// incluyendo la librería de nusopa
require_once('./nusoap-0.9.5/lib/nusoap.php');

// Configurando el web service
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("SaludoXML", "urn:SaludoXMLwsdl");
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = "urn:SaludoXMLwsdl";

// Registrando nuestra función Saludar con su parámetro nombre
$server->register(
        'Saludar', // Nombre del método
        array('nombre' => 'xsd:string'), // Parámetros de entrada
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'), // Parámetros de salida
        'urn:SaludoXMLwsdl', // Nombre del workspace
        'urn:SaludoXMLwsdl#Saludar', // Acción soap
        'rpc', // Estilo
        'encoded', // Uso
        'Saluda a la persona' // Documentación
);
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';   
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

And I have a class on android ClientWS:

```
package br.com.brunnosena.portalaluno;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONStringer;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExemploWS extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
private Context context;

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "SaludoXMLwsdl#Saludar";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "Saludar";
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "SaludoXMLwsdl";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.1.14.19/webservice/loginApp/webservice.php";

public ExemploWS(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String result = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
            OPERATION_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER10);

    // Con esta opción indicamos que el web service no es .net
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

    // Enviando un parámetro al web service
    request.addProperty("nombre", params[0]);

    try {
        // Enviando la petición al web service
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // Recibiendo una respuesta del web service
        SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                .getResponse();

        result = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();

        //httpTransport.getServiceConnection().disconnect();
    } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.v("Error", e.getMessage());
        result = e.getMessage();
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // Mostramos la respuesta del web service
    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

If I put localhost in "SOAP_ADDRESS" it works. But if I put a different url example: http://brunnosena.com.br/webService/loginApp/webservice.php it appears to me the following error:

```
V/Error: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html lang='pt-br'>@2:20 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4e7c1f54)
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Can you please check in menifest file you have given below permission android.permission.INTERNET

2. Try to change SOAP_ADDRESS = http://brunnosena.com.br/webService/loginApp/webservice.php?wsdl

I hope it will work

Comment: Thanks. 
It worked. But I put it in my domain for testing. I need to move to the domain of the company, and unfortunately it made the same mistake. [Link] http://vagas.qi.edu.br/webservice/loginApp/webservice.php [/link]. Can you help me?

Comment: Please try with this URL: http://vagas.qi.edu.br/webservice/loginApp/webservice.php?wsdl

Comment: Hi @Khushvinder.
I tried but it made a mistake.
I believe it's a locked port on this server. 
Do you know which door you could release?

Comment: For this you need to go on your hosting panel. on that place you can enable and disable the ports..

Comment: Hi @Khushvinder, but i do not know the number of port.

Comment: if you have specific hosting then i think no need to enable any port ..